# Difference between Save As and Convert in Surfer?

Tags: surfer

Is there any difference in the file saved when using "Save As" compared to "Convert" to save/convert a Surfer .grd as an ASCII .asc grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the ASC file itself. The only difference is the number of files created.

- If you save the grid as an ASC file directly, then you just have the ASC file.
- If you save the grid as a Surfer GRD, and then convert it to an ASC file, you have both the GRD and the ASC.

Thanks,
Kari